# Redirect to external link from top links section

Tags: magento-1.9, custom

I using below method to redirect to an external link, but links are appended to Magento store URL.

i tried `<prepare>false</prepare> and <prepare/>` but same issue.

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Track Your Order</label>
        <url>https://www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/trackconsignment.aspx/</url> 
        <title>Track Order</title>
       <prepare>false</prepare><urlParams/> 
        <position>100</position>
        <liParams/>
       <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
        <beforeText></beforeText>
        <afterText></afterText>
    </action>
```

UPDATE: I tried this also but same issue .

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Track Your Order</label>
        <url>www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/trackconsignment.aspx/</url> 
        <title>Track Order</title>
       <prepare/><urlParams/> 
        <position>100</position>
        <liParams/>
       <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
        <beforeText></beforeText>
        <afterText></afterText>
    </action>
```

I am getting this url http://websitename.in/www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/trackconsignment.aspx/

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491527/how-do-i-add-links-to-magento-top-links-that-redirect-to-another-domain

Comment: Basically, prepare needs to be unset because, if it is set to "true" or "false", it will append the URL to your site's base URL.

Answer (score 2):

**Try below code**

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Track Your Order</label><url>https://www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/trackconsignment.aspx</url><title>Track Your Order</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position><aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams></action>
```

**OR**

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
   <label>Track Your Order</label>
   <url>https://www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/trackconsignment.aspx</url>
   <title>Track Your Order</title>
   <prepare/>
   <urlParams/>
   <position>100</position>
   <liParams />
   <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>Track Your Order</label>
    <url>https://www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/trackconsignment.aspx/</url> 
    <title>Track Order</title>
   <prepare>false</prepare>
  <urlParams>flase</urlParams> <!--Added-->
    <position>100</position>
    <liParams/>
   <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
    <beforeText></beforeText>
    <afterText></afterText>
</action>
```

Comment: Sorry It dosn't work gives this link ----> "http://websiteName.in/https:/index/www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/"